# Получение значения radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Привет всем!
Есть такой простой код.

```
<input type="radio" class="rd_button" id="rad_id" name="rad" value="1">Часто встречаю в категориях несоответствующие ей товары <br> <input type="radio" class="rd_button" id="rad_id" name="rad" value="2">Очень много категорий, я не могу найти нужную <br> <input type="radio" class="rd_button" id="rad_id" name="rad" value="3">Я не понимаю, как сортировать товары, как пользоваться фильтрами <br> <input type="radio" class="rd_button" id="rad_id" name="rad" value="4">Мне не хватило фильтров, чтобы отсортировать нужный товар <br> <input type="radio" class="rd_button" id="rad_id" name="rad" value="5">Фильтр «Регион» показывает компании не из моего региона <br> <input type="radio" class="rd_button" id="rad_id" name="rad" value="6">При поиске мне выдает не те товары, которые я искал(а)
```

6 кнопок radiobutton.

Дальше хочу передать значение(value) на сервер с помощью ajax-запроса, но почему-то всегда какой-бы radiobutton я не выбрал передаётся значение 1(value=1).
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

вот так я передаю данные:

```
$.ajax(
  {
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'handler.php',
     data: "msg2="+$('#msg2_id').val()+"&rad="+$('#rad_id').val(),
     success: function(container)....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("body").change(function () {
  $("output").text($("input[name='rad']:checked").val())
})
```

```css
label { cursor: pointer; }
label:after { content: ""; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="radio" name="rad" value="1">Часто встречаю в категориях несоответствующие ей товары</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="rad" value="2">Очень много категорий, я не могу найти нужную</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="rad" value="3">Я не понимаю, как сортировать товары, как пользоваться фильтрами</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="rad" value="4">Мне не хватило фильтров, чтобы отсортировать нужный товар</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="rad" value="5">Фильтр «Регион» показывает компании не из моего региона</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="rad" value="6">При поиске мне выдает не те товары, которые я искал(а)</label>

<hr>

<output></output>
```

Comment: О, спасибо добрый человек!
Заработало!

Comment: @rekrut, тогда прими ответ галочкой слева.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала прочитайте про идентификаторы:

> В коде документа каждый идентификатор уникален и должен быть включён
>      лишь один раз.

Работать `RadioButton`:

`var rad = document.getElementsByName('rad');`

После выполнения команды getElementsByName переменная rad содержит массив элементов radiobutton. Именно поэтому дальнейшая работа с данной переменной должна вестись как с массивом. В следующих строках мы перебираем каждый элемент массива и проверяем, не выбран ли он.

```
for (var i=0; i<rad.length; i++) {
    if (rad[i].checked) {
        alert(rad[i].value);
    }
}
```